# Youtube API - Upload to known accounts?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am looking for a way to upload videos from a web service to a handful of **known** Youtube accounts where I am the owner (have login/pw credentials).

For instance, when a video is uploaded to this site, it should also upload to Youtube accounts A, B, and C via the API.

It seems that Youtube has an old method for authenticating accounts in this manner called ClientLogin, but it has been deprecated as of 2012 and in fact no longer works consistently (significant problems popping up as of April 2013).
[(ClientLogin Docs)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps)

The new recommended protocol is oAuth 2.0 [(docs)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#login), but I am struggling to understand - is this workflow possible via oAuth authentication? If not, is there an alternative that could handle it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [CMS account](http://www.youtube.com/t/content_management) managing those account, you can do.

Currently [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) are not working with Data API v3, hope to have them back soon.

Instead of storing login/pw credentials you must store login/refresh-token. With the refresh-token you request a new access-token after the current one has expired (after 1 hour)

The main difference is for the first time, you have to ask user to give you authorization via browser.

You can store the tokens and while you are calling the APi method, you can set the token in call to upload to that user's account

Comment: For what i understand (This CMS is about copyright.): Instead of storing login/pw credentials you must store login/refresh-token. With the refresh-token you request a new access-token after the current one has expired (after 1 hour). The main difference is that ClientLogin can be used without using a Browser program.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Given that you store login/refresh token information, can you easily decipher and switch between users in the system? Say, one request should upload to YouTube account A and the next should upload to YouTube account B - is there any way to set a "target" account (via login/token) for a given single request through the client libraries?

Comment: Yes, you can store the tokens and set the token in call to upload to that user's account.